# How to change css visibly before returning something on "window.onbeforeunload"

Tags: javascript, css, onbeforeunload

I would like to ask a question about `window.onbeforeunload`.

I consider making a covering-element appear before confirming whether to unload or not.
But the following code seems not to work fine. The dom element 'COVERALL' appears just after confirming unloading.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(event){

    $( COVERALL )
        .css('zIndex', 1000000)
        .fadeTo(1000, 1.0);

    ~~~~
    ~~~~
    some time-consuming tasks here
    ~~~~
    ~~~~

    return event.returnValue = "are you sure?";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is using an event listener to capture the event object and then prevent the default action which is to leave.

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload',
    function(e)
    {
        if (!confirm('Are you sure that you want to leave?'))
            e.preventDefault();
    }, 1);
```

Its implementation may vary between browsers though. In my Fiefox 6, it asks again to confirm once the e.preventDefault(); instruction is reached, as a security measure implemented by Mozilla.

---

**August 1st:**

Today I have tried, and, in Chromium browser, if you prevent default action without asking user for confirmation such as with a confirm box, the page will close anyways.

I did some research today about this, and I have found that it is apparently impossible to trigger a page close event from Javascript, so using a custom HTML made confirm box for this would be out. I tried creating custom events, dispatching them to various window elements and even inspecting and copying browser made events. (All this on Firefox, in Chromium I did not check because, well, no support in Firefox means not to ever rely on something like that)

**But good news for you**, I have found that if you quickly set up an XMLHttpRequest and send the information you want to save before leaving, the data sending will finish in background even if the page has been closed.

I have successfully been able to achieve that for both browsers with the following code.

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload',
function(e)
{
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('html', document.body.innerHTML);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
    xhr.open('POST', './dataRetriever.php');
    xhr.send(fd);
    // uncomment these if you want confirmation for all browsers
    // because this code will not ask for confirmation in others
    // than Mozilla powered ones.
    //if (!confirm('Leave?'))
    //  e.preventDefault();
}
, 1);
```

With that one, I send all the body innerHTML to my dataRetriever.php script so tell me how it goes and if it works for you as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. It seems like that changes in CSS made after 'event happening' doesn't appear until all tasks are done anyway. In fact what I really wanted to do was sending lots of data before an unintentional unloading, and while sending them covering the window with a semi-transparent div element in order to prevent unnecessary manipulations by users. The problem was that the div element never appeared until just before leaving the page. Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user921837 I have found how to send information, check my updated answer.

Comment: Actually I need to finish saving data before leaving the page (due to some reasons), so I wanted a browser to wait data saving synchronously. Anyway thank you very much for precise information!

Comment: Does it have to be synchronously? I think that being asynchronous should be enough if you want just to save some user information and don’t expect response from the server. I don’t think you actually expect any response from the server. If you found my answer useful please pick it as the correct answer.

Comment: It has to be synchronous because when users return to the page just after saving lots of data, they have to get all the saved data to render. If it's asynchronous, sometimes a user fails to get data which he thought he saved correctly.

Comment: Being asynchronous does not imply that there might be a lose. Better try implementing my example and to tests to make sure. If you found my answer useful please pick it as the correct answer.